# Refitting with different contrasts vs. pairwise comparisons

Tags: r, linear-model, post-hoc, contrasts

Say, I fit a linear or generalised linear model in `R` with dummy coding (`contr.treatment` for `R` users) with a specified reference group:

```
        library(lme4)
        out1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence)
                      ~ C(period, contr.treatment(4, base=1))
                      + (1 | herd),
                      data = cbpp,
                      family = binomial)
```

`period4` is the`(Intercept)`. And I see that the difference between `period1` and `period4` is significant. But what if I'm interested whether there is a difference between say `period2` and `period3`. It seems that when people encounter this case they e.g. use `glht()` from `multcomp` or `TukeysHD` to do pairwise comparisons. Couldn't I just refit the model and specify a different reference group? (I would obviously lose any p-value adjustments the aforementioned functions use but otherwise it should be similar.):

```
        out2 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence)
                      ~ C(period, contr.treatment(4, base=2))
                      + (1 | herd),
                      data = cbpp,
                      family = binomial)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. And you'll find that the few comparisons that are the same in both models will have the same estimates and standard errors. It's just more convenient for most people to have all the comparisons displayed together. Plus it is even more convenient to have the multiplicity adjustments for those tests already in place.

An additional reason, and I think it's the most important, is that it's easier to report and explain your analysis to other people when you show all the comparisons of interest in one place, as one family. Without good communication, even the best statistical analysis is useless.